# CF7 additional Mail (2) does not attach files

Tags: wordpress, email-attachments, contact-form-7

I am using Сontact form 7 and the Images Optimize and Upload CF7 plugin. I need to send 2 different emails but with the same attachment.

Mail (2) does not attach files. But everything is fine in the first mail, with the attached ones. The settings are the same.

Why can't files be attached to the second mail?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCJIl.png)

I have tried different file multi-upload plugins but the result is the same. Files comes in only one mail.

Answer (score 0):

Check the wpcf7_before_send_mail action and the add_extra_attachments function to add the attachments, for example:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'your_custom_function', 10, 3);

function your_custom_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

  $file_path = array(
    'path 1',
    'path 2',
    'path 3',
  );

  $template = 'mail'; // use 'mail' if you want to attach to the defautl email.
  $template_2 = 'mail_2'; // use 'mail_2' if you want to attach to Mail (2).

  $submission->add_extra_attachments( $file_path, $template ); // attaches to the default email
  $submission->add_extra_attachments( $file_path, $template_2 ); // attaches to mail (2)

}
```

More info on this [github issue](https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/issues/344).